# In a CherryPy dispatcher, get the original path including the query string

Tags: python, cherrypy

I have a CherryPy application with a custom dispatcher, inheriting from `cherrypy._cpdispatch.Dispatcher`. In its method `def __call__(self, path): ...`, I can get the requested path as the argument `path`. The `path` doesn't include the query string, nor does `cherrypy.url`. I've found that I can get the query string separately as `cherrypy.request.query_string`. Of course, if I raise a redirect in the dispatcher, such as

```
raise cherrypy.HTTPRedirect(transform(path), 301)
```

then the query string is lost.

I want to preserve the query string after a redirect. Is there a way to get the original path or URL, including the query string? If not, should I reconstruct it with something like `path + (if query_string then '?' + query_string else '')`, or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that `cherrypy.url` has some useful parameters.

- To get the full URL, like `"http://example.com/foo/bar?arg=1"`, say `cherrypy.url(qs = cherrypy.request.query_string)`.
- To get the full server-relative path, like  `"/foo/bar?arg=1"`, say `cherrypy.url(qs = cherrypy.request.query_string, relative = "server").`